# How to configure IIS to redirect to site

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, coldfusion

So far I downloaded and configured IIS (version 10) on my windows machine. I created a domain called `kinux`, using the hosts file, so when I navigate to `kinux.com`, I'm brought to my IIS server root directory. I then created a site called `localwww` and configured ColdFusion to run via this site.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when I go to `kinux.com`, it redirects me to my ColdFusion site. Does anyone know how to do this?

hosts

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       Kinux
127.0.0.1       Kinux.com
```

localwww site 
[image: iis]

Default site 
[image: DESKTOP-SERVER]

Comment: This is out-of-scope of DNS.  You'll want to either (i) move the cold fusion site to the root of the server; or (ii) setup an HTTP redirect from the root of the server to the cold fusion site.  Option (ii) will probably be easiest for you.  I don't remember exactly but if you click on the default site that's hosting the root there should be an option for HTTP redirects.

Comment: @bchurchill i dont have a default site. I must have deleted it when i was messing around

Comment: Did you run the ColdFusion Web Server Configuration tool to configure IIS to pass requests to ColdFusion?

Comment: @CarlVonStetten, yeah and you can see it added the folders to all the websites (sorry if its hard to see in the site) . But the index.cfm i put in there doesn't load. Kinda why im trying to redirect it to my ColdFusion root directory.

Comment: Why not just bind your localwww site to the kinux.com host name? Otherwise, install the IIS URL Rewrite module (you have to download it) `https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite`. Then configure a redirect rule on your kinux.com site.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten, well the binding ip for localww is *, which correct me if im wrong, means that it should be binding to all ip's including the kinux domain.

Comment: What is your DesktopServer site bound to?

Comment: @CarlVonStetten, added screen shot of desktop server (this is actually the default sire because the id is 1).

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you need a redirect then. When you hit kinux.com, what site is it landing at?

Comment: @CarlVonStetten it was desktop-server, but the index.cfm doesn't seem to be loading correctly. All the ISPA filter & handlers are there.Also, the domain no longer works, after i edit the iisstart.htm page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168991/discussion-between-john-and-carl-von-stetten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions that I can think of:

1. Move your ColdFusion site to port 80 and add binding for hostname "kinux.com" such that all incoming requests to kinux.com will be served by your ColdFusion site.
2. Assuming "Desktop-server" is the website that gets called when you enter "kinux.com, click on it in IIS manager. In the center panel you will find "HTTP Redirect". Set the URL of ColdFusion website here. What will happen now is any request coming in to "Desktop-server" website would be redirected to your cold fusion website.

In solution 2, an important thing to note here is that the when the first request reaches "Desktop-server" site, IIS will indicate to the client (browser from where it is being accessed) that a redirect rule has been set to the new URL. The client will now once again make a new request to the new address (ColdFusion). So please ensure that the URL you enter in HTTP redirect rule can be accessed by client machine as well.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah, adding the binding kinux.com did it, sorry it was that simple. IIS is tricky for a linux user like myself.